# Call to undefined relationship [user_id] on model [App\User]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm trying Laravel 5.4 (i usually work with 5.1) and im actually copypasting most of the code, so i dont understand what is the trouble, maybe is because there is a better way to do it but yeah, its been 1 hour and i cant get past this;
Hope you can help me with this.. 
In case this isn't enough i'll be posting my views and routes. Thank to everyone.

This is my Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'user_name', 'user_birthday'];

    public static $rules = [
        'user_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'user_birthday' => 'required'
    ];
    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
class UsersController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::with('user_id')->orderBy('user_id', 'ASC')->paginate(10);

        return view('admin.users.index')->with("user", $users);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.users.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $users = new User($request->all());
        $users->save();

        return redirect()->route('admin.users.index');
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $users = User::find($id);
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $users = User::find($id);

        return view('admin.users.edit')->with('user', $user);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $users = User::find($id);
        $users->user_name = $request->user_name;
        $users->user_birthday = $request->user_birthday;
        $users->save();

        return redirect()->route('admin.users.index');
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $users = User::find($id);
        $users->delete();

        return redirect()->route('admin.users.index');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is from the following line of code. When you use `with` on a model is to load `children relationships` or `sub-models`. That is why the application is looking for the relationship `user_id` in the User Model thinking that it's a `sub-model` of the `User model` but it's not, so it return an error.

## wrong

```
$users = User::with('user_id')->orderBy('user_id', 'ASC')->paginate(10);
```

## correct

```
$users = User::orderBy('user_id', 'ASC')->paginate(10);
```